# TImage width / height anchor not working

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, timage

I've got a TForm which has an Event `FormResize`, within that function I want to draw something within my TImage.

My FormResize function looks like below

```
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Teken de blokjes
    _viewPort->draw(_viewPortImage->Canvas, _viewPortImage->Width, _viewPortImage->Height);
}
```

Within this function I do nothing more than drawing a rectangle which draws a border:

```
ViewPort::draw(Vcl::Graphics::TCanvas* Canvas, int width, int height)
{
    Canvas->Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Now the problem. When I make the form smaller than the original it scales well. but when the form gets bigger than the original size. The background + Border is not drawn well. See the screenshot below. The white background / Canvas is from the TImage. The TImage is Anchored in all 4 directions.

Anyone knows how to also make the image able to resize bigger?

[image: Screenshot original smaller bigger]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage` and do your drawing in the `TPaintBox::OnPaint` event. Then you don't need to use the `TForm::OnResize` event anymore.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::ViewPortPaintBoxPaint(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Teken de blokjes
    _viewPort->draw(ViewPortPaintBox->Canvas, ViewPortPaintBox->ClientWidth, ViewPortPaintBox->ClientHeight);
}
```